# how to get child of div element

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="div" id="div">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col1">
             <input type="text">
             <!--I need to get a value of these inputs-->
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
             <input type="text">
             <!--I need to get a value of these inputs-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col1">
             <input type="text">
             <!--I need to get a value of these inputs-->
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
             <input type="text">
             <!--I need to get a value of these inputs-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to get values of all of inputs in div and how to check in which div input in(col1 or col2);

in my case div with class "row" will be added via firebase database.

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".div > .col");
alert(inputs.value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using JavaScript, try looping with `forEach`

```
var inputElem = document.querySelectorAll(".row input");
inputElem.forEach(function(obj){
    console.log(obj.value)
})
```

Snippet:

```js
var inputElem = document.querySelectorAll(".row input");
inputElem.forEach(function(obj){
 console.log(obj.value)
})
```

```html
<div class="div" id="div">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col1">
             <input type="text" value="one">
             <!--I need to get a value of these inputs-->
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
             <input type="text" value="two">
             <!--I need to get a value of these inputs-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col1">
             <input type="text" value="three">
             <!--I need to get a value of these inputs-->
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
             <input type="text" value="four">
             <!--I need to get a value of these inputs-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work:

```
$("div input").each(function(){
    // Get the value:
    console.log($(this).val());
    // check in which div input in(col1 or col2)
    console.log($(this).closest("div").attr("class"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const inputs = document.getElementById('div').getElementsByTagName('input');
console.log(inputs[0].value, inputs[1].value);
```

See an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/xbdd6q13/